# How to transfer items from QListWidget based in one window to another QListWidget based in another window?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qlistwidget

That being said, I would like to be able to transfer my items from QListWidget based in one window to another.

The code below allows me to transfer one item at a time,
but I am struggling to think of a way to transfer multiple items
at one time.

(Code below is from an example I found and have altered.)

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QMainWindow,
    QDialog,
    QWidget,
    QVBoxLayout,
    QLineEdit,
    QLabel,
    QPushButton,
    QListWidget,
    QAbstractItemView
    )


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.user_input = QListWidget()
        self.user_input.addItem("2")
        self.user_input.addItem("3")
        self.populate()
        self.show()
        self.user_input.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.ExtendedSelection)

    def populate(self):
        widgets = [QLabel("Insert a number"), self.user_input]
        centralWidget = self.group_widgets(widgets)
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)

    def group_widgets(self, widgets):
        parentWidget = QWidget()
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        for widget in widgets: layout.addWidget(widget)
        parentWidget.setLayout(layout)
        return parentWidget

    def when_input(self, function):
        #self.user_input.textChanged.connect(function)
        self.user_input.itemClicked.connect(self.printItemText)
        self.user_input.itemClicked.connect(function)
        
    def printItemText(self):
        items = self.user_input.selectedItems()
        x = []
        for i in range(len(items)):
            x.append(str(self.user_input.selectedItems()[i].text()))

        print (x)

class Dialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.user_input = QListWidget()
        self.relay_sum = None  # function to relay result of addition
        self.populate()
        self.show()

    def populate(self):
        widgets = self.get_widgets()
        layout = self.get_layout(widgets)
        self.setLayout(layout)

    def get_widgets(self):
        widgets = [
            QLabel("Inserted number"),
            self.user_input,
            ]
        return widgets

    def get_layout(self, widgets):
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        for widget in widgets: layout.addWidget(widget)
        return layout


def main():
    app = QApplication([])
    mainWindow = MainWindow()
    dialog = Dialog()
    mainWindow.when_input(lambda text: dialog.user_input.addItem(str(text.text())))
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Your question is unclear, in your example an item is transferred when that item is pressed. What event must happen to transfer items and what are those items?

Comment: When the item is clicked, or selected, I would like it to transfer over to the 2nd list. Currently if you click on the 2 items individually: '2', or '3', they will appear in the 2nd list, but when i shift+click multiple items it will only transfer the item that I clicked on instead of all of the highlighted items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When an item is clicked it is also selected so just use the last feature.

One possible solution is to create a new token that transports the cloned items from the selected items, and then add it to the other QListWidget.

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QAbstractItemView,
    QApplication,
    QDialog,
    QLabel,
    QListWidget,
    QMainWindow,
    QVBoxLayout,
    QWidget,
)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    custom_signal = pyqtSignal(list)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.user_input = QListWidget(selectionMode=QAbstractItemView.ExtendedSelection)
        self.user_input.addItem("2")
        self.user_input.addItem("3")
        self.populate()

        self.user_input.itemSelectionChanged.connect(self.handle_selection_changed)

    def populate(self):
        widgets = [QLabel("Insert a number"), self.user_input]
        centralWidget = self.group_widgets(widgets)
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)

    def group_widgets(self, widgets):
        parentWidget = QWidget()
        layout = QVBoxLayout(parentWidget)
        for widget in widgets:
            layout.addWidget(widget)
        return parentWidget

    def handle_selection_changed(self):
        items = []
        for item in self.user_input.selectedItems():
            items.append(item.clone())
        self.custom_signal.emit(items)


class Dialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.user_input = QListWidget()
        self.populate()

    def populate(self):
        widgets = self.get_widgets()
        layout = self.get_layout(widgets)
        self.setLayout(layout)

    def get_widgets(self):
        widgets = [
            QLabel("Inserted number"),
            self.user_input,
        ]
        return widgets

    def get_layout(self, widgets):
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        for widget in widgets:
            layout.addWidget(widget)
        return layout

    def add_items(self, items):
        for item in items:
            self.user_input.addItem(item)


def main():
    app = QApplication([])

    mainWindow = MainWindow()
    mainWindow.show()

    dialog = Dialog()
    dialog.show()

    mainWindow.custom_signal.connect(dialog.add_items)

    app.exec_()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```